# Unstringify python code for AWS cloudformation template

Tags: stringify

I have stringified version of python code that I want to unstringify it, make some changes to it and stringify it again.
Is there any library available to do the same?

**Sample Input:**

```
"import boto3\n\nSUCCESS_MESSAGE = \"Instance patched successfully\"\
                  \nFAILURE_MESSAGE = \"Patching failed and Instance restored to original\
                  \ state\"\n\nssm = boto3.client('ssm')\n\ndef is_compliant(ec2_id):\n\t\
                  report = {\n\t\t\"is_compliant\": None,\n\t\t\"items\": []\n\t}\n\tnoncompliance_found\
                  \ = False\n\ttoken = None\n\twhile 1:\n\t\tif token is None:\n\t\t\tlist_compliance_result\
                  \ = ssm.list_compliance_items(\n\t\t\t\tFilters=[{'Key': 'ComplianceType',\
                  \ 'Values': ['Patch']}],\n\t\t\t\tResourceIds=[ec2_id],\n\t\t\t\tResourceTypes=[\"\
                  ManagedInstance\"]\n\t\t\t)\n\n\t\telse:\n\t\t\tlist_compliance_result =\
                  \ ssm.list_compliance_items(\n\t\t\t\tFilters=[{'Key': 'ComplianceType',\
                  \ 'Values': ['Patch']}],\n\t\t\t\tResourceIds=[ec2_id],\n\t\t\t\tResourceTypes=[\"\
                  ManagedInstance\"],\n\t\t\t\tNextToken=token\n\t\t\t)\n\t\tcompliances =\
                  \ list_compliance_result[\"ComplianceItems\"]\n\n\t\tfor a_val in compliances:\n\
                  \t\t\tpatch_item = {\n\t\t\t\t\"PatchId\": a_val[\"Id\"],\n\t\t\t\t\"Severity\"\
                  : a_val[\"Severity\"],\n\t\t\t\t\"ComplianceType\": a_val[\"ComplianceType\"\
                  ],\n\t\t\t\t\"State\": a_val[\"Details\"][\"PatchState\"]\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\
                  \treport[\"items\"].append(patch_item)\n\t\t\tif a_val[\"Status\"] != \"\
                  COMPLIANT\" and a_val[\"Details\"][\"PatchState\"] != \"NotApplicable\"\
                  :\n\t\t\t\tnoncompliance_found = True\n\n\t\tif \"NextToken\" in list_compliance_result:\n\
                  \t\t\ttoken = list_compliance_result[\"NextToken\"]\n\t\telse:\n\t\t\tbreak\n\
                  \n\t\tif token is None:\n\t\t\tbreak\n\n\treport[\"is_compliant\"] = noncompliance_found\
                  \ is False\n\treturn report\n\n\ndef is_success_case(ec2_id):\n\treturn\
                  \ is_compliant(ec2_id)\n\n\ndef handler(event, context):\n\tcompliance_report\
                  \ = is_success_case(event[\"InstanceId\"])\n\treturn {\n\t\t\"Result\":\
                  \ SUCCESS_MESSAGE if compliance_report[\"is_compliant\"] else FAILURE_MESSAGE,\n\
                  \t\t\"PatchingSuccess\": compliance_report[\"is_compliant\"],\n\t\t\"items\"\
                  : compliance_report[\"items\"]\n\t}\n"
```

**Output**:
formatted python code
something like below:

```
import boto3

SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Instance patched successfully"
  
FAILURE_MESSAGE = "Patching failed and Instance restored to original state"

ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
....
```

and vice versa to stringify the above code.

Comment: are you asking to do this via bash or python?

Comment: Anything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of using aws cdk in and writing all of that in python instead of json?

Comment: That's a different thing. This is for an AWS SSM automation document.